# How to restrict user direct-access to folders without affecting the meta tags?

Tags: html, .htaccess, meta-tags

I have a website and I'm trying to restrict user access to root folders (i.e. when user types https://example.com/img/image.png display a blocked content message). I have written the following code on my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(\.)?domain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(\.)?domain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|js|txt|png)$ /messageforcurious [L]
```

This worked at first but now the meta-tags I have on my html files don't seem to find the og-image, apparently because of the restriction I just wrote. Here is my meta-tag.

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://example.com/img/image.png">
```

Is there any way to block user direct-access to images without affecting the meta-tags?

I have tried using relative locations for images:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="img/image.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

this will prevent direct access to all files and folders.

```
deny from all
```

To specific file type

```
<Files ~ "\.png$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```